# Using webhooks to retrieve messages from google chat api

Tags: api, bots, webhooks, google-hangouts

I'm trying to create a bot to send and receive messages through **Google Chat** and I wanted to know if there is any way I can retrieve messages **using the webhooks**? If not, is there anyway I can **request** the messages in the chat API without an public IP?

NOTE: if there isn't, I have read the https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/service-accounts and I wanted to understand: if I setup a Flask server, will google be able to send me the push notifications back, or do I need a public IP?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
There is no way, you must register on google as a developer.
Sorry for taking so long to post the solution